# Could not find message body reader with Jetty, RestEasy and Guice from exported JAR

Tags: java, jetty, jax-rs, guice, resteasy

I have this very specific problem. The application works fine when run from Eclipse (without any arguments). But gives

```
ERROR: RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class hu.edudroid.matek.web.endpoints.RequestData of content type: application/json
```

exception, when running the exported JAR (mvn clean compile assembly:single). Otherwise injection works fine, endpoints that don't rely on JSON parsing work fine. The get method works fine, the post method throws the error. I can't figure out what to do.

My server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MathModule(args));
    int port = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]):8081; 
    Server server = new Server(port);
    ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    servletHandler.addEventListener(injector.getInstance(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.class));

    ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(HttpServletDispatcher.class);
    servletHandler.addServlet(sh, "/*");

    server.setHandler(servletHandler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

My dependencies:

```
public class MathModule extends RequestScopeModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        super.configure();
        bind(TestEndpoint.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

My endpoint:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
    public String get() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
    public String post(RequestData value) {
        return "Hello " + value.getName();
    }
}
```

The POJO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestData {
    private String name;
}
```

And finally the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hu.edudroid.matek</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>core</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.47</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.5.v20170502</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.5.v20170502</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>hu.edudroid.matek.web.main.MatekServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jar-with-dependencies assembly descriptor all dependencies jars extract to one place. Sometimes this jars can contain files with the same name. In that case only file from fist jar will be included in result jar.
In your assembly file META-INF\services\javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers exists in two dependency jars (resteasy-jaxrs and resteasy-jettison-provider). Last jar contains provider for application/json content type, but without service description resteasy can't find it. You can try [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) with transformer which [concatenate service description files](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything. I'll try your suggestion.